# UIFontDescriptor pointSize vs UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute

Tags: ios, font-size, uifontdescriptor

If I have a font descriptor.

```
let fontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .headline)
```

Then what is the difference between

```
fontDescriptor.pointSize
```

and

```
fontDescriptor.object(forKey: UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute)
```

Comment: My understanding is that pointSize is just a convenience readonly property for the UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute dictionary value. Are you seeing behavior that contradicts that, or just trying to confirm that?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm just trying to confirm that.